# FastReport4: OnBeforePrint never executes on frxReport.ShowPreparedReport

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I'm using Delphi XE5.
On my GroupFooter I try to hide several memos in a conditional is met

```
procedure GroupFooter1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  ShowMessage('a');                              
  if <frxDB."total_payment"> <= 0 then begin
    Memo27.Visible := False;                                                                              
    Memo28.Visible := False;                                                                              
    Memo29.Visible := False;                                                                              
    Memo30.Visible := False;                                                                              
  end;            
end;
```

This is my calling code in Delphi

```
  Report.LoadFromFile(CurDir+'reports/invoice/'+ReportName);
  if Report.PrepareReport then
    Report.ShowPreparedReport;
```

I found that the OnBeforePrint event never fires when the report was showing after frxReport.ShowPreparedReport command, but when I tries to preview it in the designer, it works just as normal.
I keep wondering what did I miss.
Anyone can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently found out that this is due to FastReport 4 demo version that is bundled along with Embarcadero RAD Studio XE5. The full version works perfectly, but any fr3 file created from demo-bundled version can't be opened in full version.